# How to detect whether URL request is ajax in service worker fetch API

Tags: ajax, service-worker, fetch-api, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a Progressive web app. I want to cache two versions of a page

1. Normal - full page including header and footer
2. Ajax - Content only

In case of offline use, I need to detect whether request is for normal or Ajax version so I can return proper data.

Comment: It will be tricky to do it this way. But I don't think you need that. How exactly is your site build? Is it an app shell architecture (static layout etc.) that fetches the actual content via AJAX? If so, then I guess you already have the different URLs scheme for content calls and the shell calls, don't you?

Comment: Wouldn't you have two separate URLs? One for the page itself and another URL for the API from where the content is retrieved?

example: index.html makes a query to /api/people. In which case you could cache index.html and its static resources and then store the response from the API. Read more: https://medium.com/dev-channel/offline-storage-for-progressive-web-apps-70d52695513c#.hgd3yzp5s

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend going with distinct URLs for different types of requests, as suggested in the comments.

That being said, there is a way of detecting whether a given request that's passed to a service worker's `fetch` handler is for a full navigation ("normal" in your terminology) or for a resource that's loaded dynamically by a page ("Ajax" in your terminology).

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    // This is a navigation request, so respond with a
    // complete HTML document.
  } else if (event.request.mode === 'same-origin') {
    // This is a same-origin request for a resource, so
    // respond appropriately depending on event.request.url, etc.
  }
});
```

There are a few other [possible values](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) for `event.request.mode`, like `'cors'`, but you'd only see them if you're making cross-origin requests for resources.